# Simplified string alignment with a function?

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions, text-alignment

I have a python program with lots of text I want to align and `.format` seemed messy, so I planned on using `.center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns)` on the end of a `print` like so:

```
import shutil
print("Hello world!".center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns))
```

and should be returned centered in my console, and it is.

However, If I want to simplify this into a single function:

```
def align_center():
    center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns)
```

and add that to the end of a print fuction:

```
print("Hello World!".align_center())
```

(I've also tried it without the parentheses at the end of `.align_center`)

it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'align_center'
```

I'm pretty sure I had it working correctly earlier but I changed something and it stopped, **Am I crazy and this simplification via a function isn't possible? Am I applying it wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you ever had it working if you simply appended it to the string. That would make it an atrribute and the str object is unlikely to have an attribute that matches the name of an arbitrary method you created.

This might help: pass the string to the method and return it formatted. Something like this:

```
def align_center(s):
    return s.center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns)
```

then:

```
print(align_center(s))
```

Comment: You forgot to `return` in `align_center`.